# What is the mathematical rationale for the decompose() function of qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction

The decompose() function decomposes the encapsulated quantum module into sets of elementary quantum gates. But what is the math behind its operation? For example how is a diag[1,1,1,1,1-1,1,1,1,1] decomposed into the following circuit? If I also want to decompose diag[1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1] what will be its laws?

[image]